# force:lightningQuickAction remove scrollbar

Tags: aura, style, lightning-quickaction

Is there a way to remove the vertical scrollbar from my aura component which implements force:lightningQuickAction?
I would like to keep the upper section fixed and make only the lower content scrollable.
I tried:

```
.THIS .scrollable {
overflow:hidden;
```

}
But it does not work. Adding !important has also no effect.[image]

Comment: Why don’t you make your own component using the recordeditform base component? Hacking the css of namespaced components is never a good idea as they are prone to have their selectors changed with updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soultion is to add the following to your *.cmp file

```
<aura:component
 <aura:html tag="style">     
     .slds-modal__content{  
       overflow-y: hidden !important;  
     } 
 </aura:html>
 ...
</aura:component>
```